# Spring Isolation Support? MSQL Snapshot Isolation

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc, transactions

We are using SQL Server and it is possible that Snapshot isolation may be a good way to improve out performance and fix some deadlocking concerns.

Assuming that we have a real need to change to Snapshot isolation, I can't seem to find an easy way to enable Snapshot isolation on Springs `@Transactional`.

I found the following hibernate configuration option for doing it in Hibernate, however we use spring-jdbc and don't have a hibernate impl. this seems to suggest that the isolation value could be provided manually somehow.

```
<property name=”hibernate.connection.isolation”>4096</property>
```

Does anyone know of a way of getting Spring to use SQL Server Snapshot isolation on transactions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4096 is code for SNAPSHOT isolation, refer post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/angelsb/archive/2006/08/24/719013.aspx), you have to set isolation level on connection object, I don't think you can achieve this with @Transactional, you can use other transaction solutions provided by spring, mainly 'TransactionTemplate'.

Comment: Hi gbagga, helpful tip. I will look into TransactionTemplate further and report back.

Comment: Thanks gbagga, TransactionTemplate.setIsolationLevel with the correct code is exactly what we are looking for. To anyone reading this question with similar intent I have not yet configured the database and tested this; however I see no reason why it shouldn't work assuming  you configure snapshot isolation correctly (on the DB and transaction).