# jTDS SNAPSHOT isolation with spring transacion

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-transactions, jtds

Is there any way to use MSSQL SNAPSHOT transaction isolation with spring transactions?

when i try to set

```
DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
def.setIsolationLevel(4096);
```

i get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only values of isolation constants allowed
```

Spring checks that only values defined in `org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition` are used and i am trying to set value 4096 becase it corresponds with jtds setting for snapshot isolation:

```
/**
 * SQL Server custom transaction isolation level.
 */
public static final int TRANSACTION_SNAPSHOT = 4096;
```

this is in `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2`

Comment: Nice that that is the internal constant used by jTDS that isn't the same as the value used by Spring. Use the one from spring to configure spring NOT the one from jTDS (which is for internal use by jTDS only!).

Comment: I cannot, i'm trying to use a custom isolation level outside of standard JDBC/Spring values which are TRANSACTION_NONE, TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED, TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED, TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ, TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE with values 0,1,2,4,8. This SNAPSHOT level with value 4096 is unique to MSSQL and has no equivalent in JDBC and Spring constants but jtds jdbc driver supports it.

Comment: To me it looks like you want a different propagation level which would be `NESTED` which is a weird name for for snapshot support (like on oracle for instance).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983873/spring-isolation-support-msql-snapshot-isolation

Comment: NESTED? i don't know where you got that. MSSQL SNAPSHOT isolation is equivalent to the way oracle treats READ_COMMITED thats why i want it

Comment: Have you read the link I pointed you to? Or are you just dismissing my comments?

Comment: I read it, it seams using TransactionTemplate is the answer, I don't see anything there about "NESTED" and don't know where you got that from. I will try to use TransactionTemplate like recommended in the link you provided